# SQL Server - Include NULL using UNPIVOT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, unpivot

`UNPIVOT` will not return `NULL`s, but I need them in a comparison `query`. I am trying to avoid  using `ISNULL` the following example (Because in the real sql there are over 100 fields):

```
Select ID, theValue, column_name
From 
(select ID,
  ISNULL(CAST([TheColumnToCompare]  AS VarChar(1000)), '') as TheColumnToCompare
  from MyView
  where The_Date = '04/30/2009'
) MA
UNPIVOT
   (theValue FOR column_name IN 
   ([TheColumnToCompare])
) AS unpvt
```

Any alternatives?

Comment: I don't want to wrap 100+ columns with any type of function or other coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dynamic SQL and COALESCE, I solved the problem like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @dataCols NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
    @dataCols = COALESCE(@dataCols + ', ' + 'ISNULL(' + Name + ',0) ' + Name , 'ISNULL(' + Name + ',0) ' + Name )
FROM Metric WITH (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY ID

SELECT 
    @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ', ' + Name , Name )
FROM Metric WITH (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY ID

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ArchiveID, MetricDate, BoxID, GroupID, ID MetricID, MetricName, Value
            FROM 
               (SELECT ArchiveID, [Date] MetricDate, BoxID, GroupID,  ' + @dataCols + '
                FROM MetricData WITH (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN Archive WITH (NOLOCK)
                    ON ArchiveID = ID
                WHERE BoxID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), @BoxID) + '
                AND GroupID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), @GroupID) + ') p
            UNPIVOT
               (Value FOR MetricName IN 
                  (' + @cols + ')
            )AS unpvt
            INNER JOIN Metric WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON MetricName  = Name
            ORDER BY MetricID, MetricDate'

EXECUTE( @SQL )
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the way to go in these cases.

Answer (score 26):

To preserve NULLs, use CROSS JOIN ... CASE:

```
select a.ID, b.column_name
, column_value = 
    case b.column_name
      when 'col1' then a.col1
      when 'col2' then a.col2
      when 'col3' then a.col3
      when 'col4' then a.col4
    end
from (
  select ID, col1, col2, col3, col4 
  from table1
  ) a
cross join (
  select 'col1' union all
  select 'col2' union all
  select 'col3' union all
  select 'col4'
  ) b (column_name)
```

Instead of:

```
select ID, column_name, column_value
From (
  select ID, col1, col2, col3, col4
  from table1
  ) a
unpivot (
  column_value FOR column_name IN (
    col1, col2, col3, col4)
  ) b
```

A text editor with column mode makes such queries easier to write. UltraEdit has it, so does Emacs. In Emacs it's called rectangular edit.

You might need to script it for 100 columns.

Comment: I'd script it for more than 5 columns, but I'm lazy that way :-). Here's an example: `select 'select ''' + column_name + ''' UNION ALL'  FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'table1' and table_schema = 'dbo'`

Answer (score 19):

It's a real pain.  You have to switch them out before the `UNPIVOT`, because there is no row produced for `ISNULL()` to operate on - code generation is your friend here.

I have the problem on `PIVOT` as well.  Missing rows turn into `NULL`, which you have to wrap in `ISNULL()` all the way across the row if missing values are the same as `0.0` for example.

Comment: CROSS JOIN ... CASE will preserve nulls. See below for an example.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same problem. Using `CROSS APPLY` (SQL Server 2005 and later) instead of `Unpivot` solved the problem. I found the solution based on this article [An Alternative (Better?) Method to UNPIVOT](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CROSS+APPLY+VALUES+UNPIVOT/91234/)
and I made the following example to demonstrate that CROSS APPLY will NOT Ignore NULLs like `Unpivot`.

```
create table #Orders (OrderDate datetime, product nvarchar(100), ItemsCount float, GrossAmount float, employee nvarchar(100))

 insert into #Orders
 select getutcdate(),'Windows',10,10.32,'Me'
 union 
 select getutcdate(),'Office',31,21.23,'you'
 union 
 select getutcdate(),'Office',31,55.45,'me'
 union  
 select getutcdate(),'Windows',10,null,'You'

SELECT OrderDate, product,employee,Measure,MeasureType
 from #Orders orders
 CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES ('ItemsCount',ItemsCount),('GrossAmount',GrossAmount)
    ) 
    x(MeasureType, Measure) 


SELECT OrderDate, product,employee,Measure,MeasureType
from #Orders orders
UNPIVOT
   (Measure FOR MeasureType IN 
      (ItemsCount,GrossAmount)
)AS unpvt;


 drop table #Orders
```

Answer (score 3):

or, in SQLServer 2008 in shorter way:

```
...
cross join 
(values('col1'), ('col2'), ('col3'), ('col4')) column_names(column_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found left outer joining the UNPIVOT result to the full list of fields, conveniently pulled from INFORMATION_SCHEMA, to be a practical answer to this problem in some contexts.

```
-- test data
CREATE TABLE _t1(name varchar(20),object_id varchar(20),principal_id varchar(20),schema_id varchar(20),parent_object_id varchar(20),type varchar(20),type_desc varchar(20),create_date varchar(20),modify_date varchar(20),is_ms_shipped varchar(20),is_published varchar(20),is_schema_published varchar(20))
INSERT INTO _t1 SELECT 'blah1', 3, NULL, 4, 0, 'blah2', 'blah3', '20100402 16:59:23.267', NULL, 1, 0, 0 

-- example
select c.COLUMN_NAME, Value
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
left join (
  select * from _t1
) q1
unpivot (Value for COLUMN_NAME in (name,object_id,principal_id,schema_id,parent_object_id,type,type_desc,create_date,modify_date,is_ms_shipped,is_published,is_schema_published)
) t on t.COLUMN_NAME = c.COLUMN_NAME
where c.TABLE_NAME = '_t1'
</pre>
```

output looks like:

```
+----------------------+-----------------------+
|    COLUMN_NAME       |        Value          |
+----------------------+-----------------------+
| name                 | blah1                 |
| object_id            | 3                     |
| principal_id         | NULL                  | <======
| schema_id            | 4                     |
| parent_object_id     | 0                     |
| type                 | blah2                 |
| type_desc            | blah3                 |
| create_date          | 20100402 16:59:23.26  |
| modify_date          | NULL                  | <======
| is_ms_shipped        | 1                     |
| is_published         | 0                     |
| is_schema_published  | 0                     |
+----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: The only downside of this is that all of your source fields have to be contiguously typed.

Comment: @Ozziemedes I think you might be missing the point, even the OP casts the original data to varchar... at some point in all these techniques, the original types must be lost due to the fundamental nature of an unpivot returning what were previously different columns, under a single column. Also, are you sure you're using the word "contiguous" properly? The definition of that word means "next to each other", not "the same" as it seems you intended?

Comment: LOL.  In context: I was looking for a way to unpivot less strongly typed data when I came across this post.  I wasn't making a criticism - just an observation.  I certainly wasn't expecting to have my head ripped off, but "welcome to the internet" and all that. *sigh*

Answer (score 2):

I had your same problem and this is
my quick and dirty solution :

your query :

```tsql
 select 
     Month,Name,value 
     from TableName 
 unpivot     
  (        
   Value  for Name in (Col_1,Col_2,Col_3,Col_4,Col_5
  )
) u
```

replace with :

```tsql
select Month,Name,value from 
    ( select 
          isnull(Month,'no-data') as Month,
          isnull(Name,'no-data') as Name,
          isnull(value,'no-data') as value from TableName
    ) as T1
unpivot
(
    Value 
    for Name in (Col_1,Col_2,Col_3,Col_4,Col_5)  
) u
```

ok the null value is replaced with a string, but all rows will be returned !!

Answer (score 1):

Writing in May'22 with testing it on AWS Redshift.
You can use a with clause where you can coalesce the columns where nulls are expected. Alternatively, you can use coalesce in the select statement prior to the UNPIVOT block.

And don't forget to alias with the original column name (Not following won't break or violate the rule but would save some time for coffee).

```
Select ID, theValue, column_name
From 
(select ID,
  coalesce(CAST([TheColumnToCompare]  AS VarChar(1000)), '') as TheColumnToCompare
  from MyView
  where The_Date = '04/30/2009'
) MA
UNPIVOT
   (theValue FOR column_name IN 
   ([TheColumnToCompare])
) AS unpvt
```

OR

```
WITH TEMP1 as (
select ID,
  coalesce(CAST([TheColumnToCompare]  AS VarChar(1000)), '') as TheColumnToCompare
  from MyView
  where The_Date = '04/30/2009'
)

Select ID, theValue, column_name
From 
(select ID, TheColumnToCompare
  from MyView
  where The_Date = '04/30/2009'
) MA
UNPIVOT
   (theValue FOR column_name IN 
   ([TheColumnToCompare])
) AS unpvt
```

Comment: Changing IsNull to Coalesce?

Answer (score -1):

ISNULL is half the answer.  Use NULLIF to translate back to NULL.  E.g.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(
    Foo varchar(50),
    Bar varchar(50) NULL
    );

INSERT INTO @temp( Foo,Bar )VALUES( 'licious',NULL );

SELECT * FROM @temp;

SELECT 
    Col,
    NULLIF( Val,'0Null' ) AS Val 
FROM(
    SELECT
        Foo,
        ISNULL( Bar,'0Null' ) AS Bar
    FROM
        @temp
    ) AS t
UNPIVOT(
    Val FOR Col IN(
        Foo,
        Bar 
        )
    ) up;
```

Here I use "0Null" as my intermediate value.  You can use anything you like.  However, you risk collision with user input if you choose something real-world like "Null".  Garbage works fine "!@#34())0" but may be more confusing to future coders.  I am sure you get the picture.

Comment: OP is asking about `unpivot`, not `pivot`. Please revise your answer if possible.

Comment: If you know anything about this topic.. you would understand that the solution works equally as well for UNPIVOT.  I will not make the trivial change until you request others retract their solutions which have nothing to do with PIVOT or UNPIVOT e.g. Cross Joins, Dynamic SQL, and auditor jokes.  The fact is, my solution is the *only* one which provides an answer to the original question.

Comment: The answer at the top worked well enough for OP to be accepted. Regardless of the triviality (which, as an analyst who works with MSSQL on a daily basis, I do realize), you have failed to answer the question according to the rules of this site as defined in [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Others' posts do not dictate what is/isn't allowed. I'm not trying to be a jerk here - I was specifically tasked by the community to review this post, as it was one of your first.

Comment: I understand well enough how to answer a specific question asked.  It is my opinion that other posters have violated your rules.  I held that opinion before I even offered my solution.  Imagine my surprise when I am the one being flagged!  Regardless, I will not change my post.  Give it a -1 if you must or remove it.  However, I think that anyone else coming to this site for an answer on how to preserve NULL in a UNPIVOT or PIVOT will find my answer helpful.

Comment: Certain other posts were flagged as well. The edit may be minor, but it *is* important... we have many newbies that come here for answers, and might not immediately see the connection between your answer and the initial post. If you make the edit, I'll be able to remove the -1 and the mod assigned to review my flag will likely decline it.

Comment: Again, my answer was / is on topic.  You can check the accepted answer from Cade Roux who introduced PIVOT as part of his answer thereby bringing PIVOT into the scope of this thread.  My response was in regards to that.  Note: it was your own content reviewer who took this thread off topic --> "CROSS JOIN ... CASE will preserve nulls. See below for an example. –  Peter Radocchia Jun 17 '09 at 13:47".  Now, I can tell you that CROSS JOINs have nothing at all to do with perserving NULLs in a PIVOT statement.  In fact, cross joins are the old technique that PIVOT was meant to replace in SQL '05.